# Handling DoS from untrusted sockets (and other streams)

Tags: tcl

[This TIP](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/287.html) confused me. It seems to be saying that `-buffering line` makes the input buffer infinitely large, when I thought line buffering only affected flushing of output? Can't I use `-buffersize 5000` together with `-buffering line` to protect me from people sending long lines? If I can, then what good is `chan pending`? To discover when the buffer is full without a line break in it?

Or are there two different buffers? One that's just for pre-reading data to save time, and one internal that commands like `gets` and `read` use?

EDIT: Or is the problem created only when you use `gets` because it doesn't return partial lines? Does `gets` put the stream into an infinite large buffer mode because otherwise if the buffer filled up without a line break, gets could never return it? Is this the "line buffer mode" that the TIP talks about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the `-buffersize` option is for *output*, not input. I've never needed to set it in the past few years; Tcl's buffer management is pretty good.

Secondly, the `-buffering` option is *also* for output.

Thirdly, you're vulnerable to someone sending you a vastly long line if you're using blocking channels. You just have no opportunity to do anything other than wait for the end of the line (or the end of the file) to come.

But in non-blocking mode, things are more subtle. You get a readable `fileevent` for the channel (not relevant for files, but you can check their size is sane more easily, and they're not normally a problem in any case) and do a `gets $theChannel line`, which returns a -1. (If 0 or more, you've got a complete line.)

So what does the -1 mean? Well, it means that either the line is incomplete or you've got to the end of the stream. You can distinguish the cases with `fblocked`/`chan blocked` (or `eof` to detect the reverse case) and you find that the line isn't there yet. What now? Check to see how much data has been buffered with `chan pending input`; if there's a silly amount (where “silly” is tunable) then it's time to give up on the channel as the other side isn't being nice (i.e., just `close` it).

I've yet to see a real use for `chan pending output` that isn't happier with writable fileevents, but it's not usually a big problem: just using `fcopy`/`chan copy` to spool data from large sources to the (slow) output channel works fine without bloating buffers a lot.